# Two approach to same question about poisson distribution leads to different answers.

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

> **Question:** Let a book of 500 pages contain 30 printing mistakes. Let
>   these errors are randomly distributed throughout the book and the
>   number of errors per page has a poisson distribution. The probability
>   that 10 pages selected at random is free from error is ______________.

---

**($1^{st}$ approach):**

Error probability(error per page) $p = \frac{30}{500} = 0.06$

No. of pages to consider $n = 10$

So, poisson parameter $\lambda = n * p = 0.6$

Now, as distribution is poisson so, $P_X(x) = \frac{e^{-\lambda}*\lambda^x}{x!}$

So according to that required probability = $P_X(0) = e^{-0.6} = 0.5488$ .

---

**$2^{nd}$ approach**:

Now, let's consider probability of no error in page. So $p = 0.94$

And we have to consider $10$ pages so $n = 10$.

Now, $\lambda = n*p = 9.4$

Now required probability is(same as all 10 pages have no errors) $P_X(10) = \frac{e^{-9.4}*9.4^{10}}{10!} = 0.1227$

---

Please point out the reason of this mismatch. Thanks.

Comment: You said " errors per page" have poisson distribution not "no errors per page" have poisson distribution. Right?

Comment: Yes I that's right.

Comment: Then how do you know "no errors per page" have poisson distribution?

Comment: Yes I got your point. Actually I thought that second approach is wrong somehow but I could not came up with reason. That you provided. Thnks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General statement:  both approaches are wrong, although the first is a good approximation, using Poisson distribution for all the errors (per page is irrelevant). The second approach makes no sense to me.

Approximate answer:  prob. no errors on one page $=.94$, so probability no errors on ten pages $=.94^{10}=0.5386$  This is approximate since independence is assumed for number of errors per page.

Exact answer (no independence assumption):  prob. of no errors on ten pages $=(1-\frac{30}{500})(1-\frac{30}{499})...(1-\frac{30}{491})$ Here the basic idea is that if there are no errors on a given page, the probability of an error on another page is slightly increased.

Comment: I understood your answer. And also got the point that this is not the place where we can apply poisson distribution. But then question itself says that error per page follows poisson distribution.

Comment: If I had question reframed as "rate of errors per page $p = 30/500$ and no. of errors per page folllows poisson distribution" then is first approach correct or still it is not.

Comment: If the number of errors total is exactly 30, then Poisson for ten pages is approximate.  Your first approach needs 30 to be a mathematical expectation to be exact. I suspect my exact answer will be very close to the result you got.

Comment: 0.535489 is exact answer -tedious calculation.